# In Cardboard VR, How to make changes on one side of the Split screen?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

For developing an app through unity, I want to create a video player basically which plays the same video but I want to control the Blurring on one side of the video. I mean INDUCE Blurring to it in a controlled manner.
If anyone could help out, i would like to share it in Detail

Comment: Post your video code that is currently working then you'll get help with code to blur the video.

Comment: You might want to look at the [Unity Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you integrate ffmpeg as a encoder and then render that to a texture htat you integrate with a c++ plugin to unity. You can crate a raw GL texture in unity that can be sedn to the "script world" of unity.

An example of such is functionality can be seen in "Mobile Movie Texture" - that's a plugin you can buy from the assetstore that gives you playback from the theora movie format.

After rendeirng the movie you want to blur it, you can use a gaussuan blur shader and apply that to the texture. ( google gaussian blur , ther eis a ton of info about that on the internet ) - There is also a boxblur shader that comes with the standard unity shaders you can use as well as a mobile blur shader ( which is a box blur )

These shaders an bet tweaked how much your blur them.